# Workflow UI in Java

Tags: java, swing, workflow, swt, awt

Does anyone know of a Java (Swing) based UI framework for building a Workflow application?

-Users are given a set of activities
-They can drag and drop these activities
-Link activities to each other (workflow steps)

Comment: Why did u add `swt` tag?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most widely used is [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html).

While I like, the Netbeans Visual Library more (and [Geerjan's articles](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/custom_layouts_in_visual_library) about it), I saw JGraph integrated in far more products, and the manual is also quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Netbeans Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/)**. Since it is a library - it can be used even if Netbeans in not the IDE you're using.